# Updating Multiple Documents In Mongoose With Different Values Each -- Express Js

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, backend

I'm stuck on a problem while developing my back end for my Application. I run Express on my back end with Mongoose. I have a model of Users, which is like this;

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, match: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/ },
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }, // using this one
    fullName: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    points: { type: Number, required: true }, // this one
    status: { type: String, require: true }, // & this one
    position: { type: String, required: true },
    verficationKey: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Now, I want to update **ON MANY USERS** the "status" and "points" keys. But for each user they might - and probably will - differ. For example lets say one user might already have 10 points and must be getting +15 and another one might have 25 and must be getting +5. I want to find my users in my DB using their "username" key (since it's unique and i can access it easily via my front end). I don't know if this is possible at all...im kinda new to express & mongo so please be patient and explain - if possible.

- I have messed around with `User.updateMany` and even `User.find().where(...).in(...)` with the second one making some progress but could not save the users to my DB probably writing something wrong :(

---

- EDIT / UPDATE

Here is the code I currently found for (kind-of) run what I need. But first its a mess and secondly, its bad.

```
    router.put('/update/points', (req, res, next) => {
    User.find().where('username').in(req.body.uid)
        .exec()
        .then(result => {
            var points = req.body.points;

            result.forEach((item) => {
                points.forEach((user) => {
                    if (item.username === user[0]) {
                        item.points = user[1];
                        item.status = user[2]
                        item.position = user[3];
                        item.save()
                            .then()
                            .catch()
                    }
                })
            })

            res.status(200).json({
                message: "Success"
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            })
        })
})
```

This is what i came up with but im not at all satisfied. After playing with it for a couple of hours i found this "solution". But clearly its bad and inefficient.

Previous to this i did similar things. This one seems to work but i hate it.

- Also a note here. In my body i send an object looking something like this from my front end;

  {
  "uid": ["user1", "user2", "user3"],
  "points":
  [
  ["user1", 10],
  ["user2", 5],
  ["user3", 25]
  ]
  }

So with this "solution" i have no other option but to write inefficient code to my front side too.

Comment: Could you do an aggregation to retrieve all users and then loop through them to make the updates? Not sure if there's a clean to do what you're wanting using `updateMany()`.

Comment: Well i did that but i had troubles saving the objects back to the database, even though changes where made correctly to the objects. So i'm kinda stuck :/

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code that you're using to save the data back?

Comment: I updated my question giving the code im currently using. If you can give me any hints i would be happy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason why you can't merge the `uid` array and the `points` array into something like this? It would make it way easier to process the data on the server.

```
[ 
    { username: "user1", points: 10, status: 8, position: 21 }, 
    { username: "user2", points: 6, position: 4 },
    { username: "user3", points: 9 },
    ... 
]
```

Then you could do something like this on the server:

```
router.put('/update/points', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        for (let user of req.body.users) {
            let targetUser = await User.findOne({ username: user.username });
            if (targetUser) {
                // Make the changes and save
                targetUser.points = user.hasOwnProperty("points") ? user.points : targetUser.points;
                targetUser.status = user.hasOwnProperty("status") ? user.status : targetUser.status;
                targetUser.position = user.hasOwnProperty("position") ? user.position : targetUser.position;
                await targetUser.save();
            }
        }

        res.status(200).json({
            message: "Success"
        });
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Huuuugeee thank you man! It works like a charm. I love it. And as far as you say for the one array in the front end, sicne my backend was like this i was forced to send 2 seperate arrays from my frontent. This is easier for my frontend & my backend code! Huge thanks for your time!